# Spring: Unique Id validator without using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, unique-constraint, customvalidator

What is the best way to check by validator to don't have duplicate ID when you do a POST?

I tried to create a custom validator but I get always an `Internal Server Error`

> {
>       "timestamp": "2020-04-25T14:37:19.158+0000",
>       "status": 500,
>       "error": "Internal Server Error",
>       "message": "HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'com.omega.mtest.validator.IdConstraint' validating type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'id'",
>       "path": "/user"
>   }

This is my model class

```
    public class User {

        @IdConstraint
        @Min(value = 1, message = "ID can't be zero or null")
        @Max(value = 1000000, message = "We collect a billion records")
        private int id;



        @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z ]*$", message = "Input doesn't match for a full name")
        private String name;

        @Min(value = 10)
        @Max(value = 120, message = "We didn't expect that age")
        private int age;

        @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z ]*$", message = "Input doesn't match for a city name")
        private String city;

        public User(int id, String name, int age, String city) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.city = city;
        }

       //getters
    }
```

Custom Validator Interface:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = UserValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface IdConstraint {

    String message() default "The input list cannot contain two ugual IDs";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Class implementation of the interface

```
public class UserValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IdConstraint, List<User>> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(IdConstraint constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<User> users, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (users.size() == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < users.size(); j++) {
                    if (i != j) {
                        if (users.get(i).getId() == users.get(j).getId()) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Controller class:

```
@Validated
@RestController
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    public UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.createUser(user), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    ResponseEntity<String> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Not valid due to validation error: " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return userService.findUserById(id);
    }
}
```

UserService

```
public interface UserService {

    List<User> getAllUsers();

    User createUser(User user);

    User findUserById(int id);

    List<User> list();
}
```

Repo

```
@Component
public class UserRepository implements UserService {

    private List<User> users;

    public UserRepository() {
        users = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return users.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public User createUser(User user) {
        users.add(user);
        return user;
    }


    @Override
    public User findUserById(int id) {
        return users.stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getId() == id)
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> list() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this way, and it's working:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    Optional<User> check = userService.findUserById(user.getId());
    if (check.isPresent()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.createUser(user), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}



@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable int id) {
        if (userService.findUserById(id).isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.findUserById(id).get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your validator signature is not correct.

You're not validate list of users here but an Integer .

Like this

```java
public class UserIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IdConstraint, Integer> {
```

Then you have to ask your service if the id is already used.

```java
public class UserIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IdConstraint, Integer> {

    @Autowired
    Private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(IdConstraint constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer id, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
         return !userService.existsById(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a bug, I can put two record with the same id :)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand ?

Comment: updated... but the logic is not the important part here ... resolve your exception first :-). Btw change int to Integer to User type

Comment: I got an error, bug, on this way I can have 2 id with the same int.

Comment: @CodeScale Why you need to get all the user from database ? which is very costly operation and useless thing.

Comment: Actually I don't care on what happened behind the `userService`  here my goal is to fix his validator.

Comment: Btw I update my answer with something like `return valid if not exists`

Comment: @CodeScale Seriously you don't care and updated the solution :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using `@IdConstraint` in the wrong place means on `private int id`. You have to put this on `List<User>`. And your validator work when you have list of user and any on two user don't have same id in request body.
You can solve this 2 way.

**Checking is service:**

Here in post endpoint you are using one user as a request body. So you can check if id exists in the database in service using `getById()` of the repository. If exist then raise exception otherwise insert.

```
User user= userRepository.getById(user.getId());
if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(user)) {
  throw new UserNotFoundException();
}
```

**Using Validator:**

It is not a better approach to call repository in validator function.
But still, you want you can do like this.

```
public class UserIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IdConstraint, Integer> {

    @Autowired
    Private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(IdConstraint constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer id, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      User user= userService.findUserById(id);
      if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(user)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: to be honest the request of the post was to don't get duplicate id. Your approach is to rise an exception if we don't find the user, id.

Comment: I am thinking your passing Id in request body then what is the question about ?
You can use validator approach also. But you don't need to fetch whole userlist for  that(accepted solution)

Comment: No fetch all user anymore ;-)

Comment: `You have to put this on List<User>. `  why?? The post contains a user... it is the user you validate...not a list of users...

Comment: @CodeScale Yes becasue validator defination like that `public class UserValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IdConstraint, List<User>> {
`

Comment: Yep but this is not correct... it is actually the bug.

Comment: I think the solution of @CodeScale it's easy and on what I wanted to do.

Comment: @CodeScale Validator is not wrong, where it is used is wrong

Comment: @OutOfMemoryError It's up to you, I am just trying to give you good solution not only fix your problem

Comment: @Eklavya thank you. Then I need to merge the 2 solutions for isValid(), first to check duplicate Id, and then to support findUserById(), isn't it?

Comment: @OutOfMemoryError nope you can use only validator solution

Comment: @Eklavya: Do you meant your solution?

Comment: I give you 2 way to solve it. 1st one checking in service just or 2nd way use validator just. Not using them both

Comment: And yes my solution

Comment: Sorry but load User is not better than check directly in database if the id is already used...it even worse.... btw you said put the constraint on list of user and then write your validator on an Integer...

Comment: @Eklavya: i tried both your solutions but I got the same response: status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",

Comment: Are you sending null or any value in id field ?

Comment: @Eklavya a correct Id. {
 "id":3,
 "name": "luigi",
 "age": 58,
 "city": "Rome"
}

Comment: Can you give me what exception you are getting in logs and what is your expected behavior ?

Comment: "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "IdConstraint.user.id",
                "IdConstraint.id",
                "IdConstraint.int",
                "IdConstraint"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "user.id",
                        "id"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "id",
                    "code": "id"

Comment: @OutOfMemoryError Actually I mean logs(application logs) exception and 400 is expected response if you are trying with existing id.